# Color console.log timestamps?

Tags: node.js, console

So, I'm using this code from 6 years ago and would like to color the timestamps however I don't know where to put the colors.

```
var log = console.log;

console.log = function () {
    var first_parameter = arguments[0];
    var other_parameters = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    function formatConsoleDate (date) {
        var hour = date.getHours();
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var seconds = date.getSeconds();

        return '[' +
               ((hour < 10) ? '0' + hour: hour) +
               ':' +
               ((minutes < 10) ? '0' + minutes: minutes) +
               ':' +
               ((seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds: seconds) +
               '] ';
    }

    log.apply(console, [formatConsoleDate(new Date()) + first_parameter].concat(other_parameters));
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I was able to color the timestamps without any modules or anything by putting a color at the END of every console.log, and it colors the next line. I would assume there is a better way to do this however.
`console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', 'colored word',' \x1b[32m\x1b[0');`That for example, would color the consoles timestamps green.

Answer (score 0):

Check the article on the Node.js knowledgebase: [How to get colors on the command line](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-get-colors-on-the-command-line/)